# Mysql DB can't establish connection

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, varnish

I run a viral news site, it's running on a 30 dollar digitalocean vps currently, with wordpress and apache.

The other day my post went viral and i was getting 250 pageviews per minute.

After a couple of minutes I then noticed that my site went down and I was seeing an error, something along the lines of error establishing connection to database.

I myself am not a technical person, but understand all the parts involved in optimizing sites.

I have consulted with some devs who have said I need to set the server up with nginx and varnish then do all the usual front end optimizations.

So far I understand that the mysql database was being queried too many times and because there was no caching in place, this caused it too blow.

What would be the best setup in this case?

I am thinking of setting up AWS instances with elastic load balancers, nginx and varnish.

The site is literally images, writing and ad units. Not much changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need two thing:

- Page Caching, which Nginx can do just fine
- A CDN, such as [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), which has a free option.

Page caching means instead of generating a page live using code and a database it just saves the page that person 1 requests, so person 2, 3, 4, etc can access it. If your site changes often you can use [Microcaching](https://www.nginx.com/blog/benefits-of-microcaching-nginx/).

A CDN means all your images will be served from a network of computers around the world. For this to work you need to have your headers set up correctly. Nginx can also do this, but you need to compile in the headers-more module. This is quite easy.

All of this is covered in my [Nginx tutorial](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/). Note that I suggest you use EasyEngine, don't do it all by hand. Later parts of the tuutorial tell you how to change caching headers and how to set up a CDN. No need to move to AWS if you don't want to, DO has a good reputation and with caching and CloudFlare your server should be absolutely fine.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'll take a look at the guide. What do you mean by setting the headers? Also, for cloud flare I'm going to presume you are suggesting the business option of 200 usd a month. Lastly, which DO instance would you recommend?

Comment: HTTP headers, particularly the caching headers. Google "http caching headers" to learn more. CloudFlare consider the free option unless you need something more. With page caching I'd keep the DO instance you have now, but do some benchmarking to see what you need - apache bench or siege are useful tools, or there are cloud benchmarking tools that are better but cost a little ($20 - $100) but are worthwhile in some cases. If you don't understand this stuff at all you may need to retain some technical help.